Using async/await with a service call
I'm having trouble understanding how to use async/await in this scenario. I have a function GetAdditionalProducts() that calls a service and returns a result. I call that function elsewhere where I need access to that result but it executes that code before the response is available. How can I use async/await to wait for the reponse before moving on?
  onSearch() {
    this.GetAdditionalProducts();
    //other stuff that requires the response from above function
  }   

  GetAdditionalProducts() {
    this.proposalService.getProductList(this.filter).subscribe(response => {
      this.additionalProducts = response.productList;
    });
  }


"Services" are nothing which TypeScript offers. Are you talking about Angular Services and HTTP calls with HttpClient?

Yes I am talking about that.

You almost never have to use async/await in Angular. Any reason why you want to?

When you think of observables, consider it normal to place the additional actions inside the subscribe. The code in the subscribe is asynchronous (waits for the API to complete) the code below the subscribe is synchronous (does not wait for completion) so you need to move the code inside to chain the actions.
When working with observables converting to promise and back seems a bit extra effort and should be done only when there is an absolute need to.
  onSearch() {
    this.GetAdditionalProducts();
  }   

  GetAdditionalProducts() {
    this.proposalService.getProductList(this.filter).subscribe(response => {
      this.additionalProducts = response.productList;
      this.additionalActions();
    });
  }

  additionalActions() {
    //other stuff that requires the response from above function
  }


I see you are using "subscribe", which imply RxJS. You could use the lastValueFrom function to convert your observable to a promise.
import { lastValueFrom } from 'rxjs'

async GetAdditionalProducts() {
    return lastValueFrom(this.proposalService.getProductList(this.filter))
}

If you want to make your own implementation, you could wrap your this.proposalService.getProductList(this.filter) call into a promise and then resolve the promise in your "subscribe" callback.
Whatever you pass to the Promise's resolve will be the return value of your promise, and accessible when using await on the function.
 async GetAdditionalProducts() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.proposalService.getProductList(this.filter).subscribe(response => {
        resolve(response.productList);
      });
    })
  }


And then, you can call the GetAdditionalProducts and awaiting the response.
async onSearch() {
  this.additionalProducts = await this.GetAdditionalProducts();
}

Edit:
The new standard for transforming an observable to a promise seams to be lastValueFrom. I've edited my answer. Thank you Bojan for pointing it out.

toPromise is still better than using new Promise yourself. Notice that you forgot to handle errors.

I did, as it was not handled in the original code. I could add the error handling but the example i've produced are not supposed to be used as is, rather they are used to demonstrate how one might implement promises by themselves.

Don't use toProimse, it's deprecated. Use lastValueFrom instead

@BojanKogoj thank you for pointing it out. I've edited my answer to use lastValueFrom rather than toPromise.
